# Mysql datetime index is not working while using 'like'

Tags: mysql, indexing

I created a table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE index_test(
   moment DATETIME,
   one_more_attr VARCHAR(10)
);
ALTER TABLE index_test ADD INDEX(moment);
```

There're two query strings:

```
A: `SELECT * FROM index_test WHERE moment LIKE '2015-06-08%'` 

B: `SELECT * FROM index_test WHERE moment BETWEEN '2015:06:08 00:00:00' AND '2015:06:08 23:00:00'`
```

Using the 'explain' statement, I found that statement B is using the index, but A not.

And when I make 'moment' varchar, they both use the index. Is anybody can tell me the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL the `DATETIME` type is stored internally as an 8 byte number, and *not* as a text string.  Therefore, the index you created on the `moment` column will work for looking up a given numerical date *value*.

In your query:

```
SELECT * FROM index_test WHERE moment LIKE '2015-06-08%'
```

the MySQL engine first implicitly casts the `moment` column to a `VARCHAR` type and then does the comparison against `'2015-06-08%'`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this query:

> SELECT * FROM index_test WHERE moment LIKE '2015-06-08%'

MySQL has to convert all datetime values to String in order to make the comparison.

So it cannot use the index.